# Making cooke domain work on LAN server

Tags: session-cookies, lan, phpbb

I i have local server **192.168.1.40** and added subdomain in my client computer **hotsts** file like **forum.mysite.com 192.168.1.40**  then installed PHPbb on that domain, now when i trying to login as asmin it keep redirecting me out of admin interface. I realized that it must be cookie domain issue.

What cookie domain i need to set in this case? Currently its set to **orum.mysite.com**

Answer (score 1):

If you use **.mysite.com** for the cookie domain it should work - note the leading '.' (period/full stop) at the beginning which should be present, that's not a typo.

If you still have trouble after that, try this [KB article](https://www.phpbb.com/kb/article/fixing-incorrect-cookie-settings) on fixing cookie settings